# How to group inside group?

Tags: jasper-reports

I have the following situation:

Each row in my database have a GROUP LETTER (can be any letter choose by user), like this:

```
   ROW1 - A 
   ROW2 - A
   ROW3 - F
   ROW4 - F
   ROW5 - K
```

So, in the exemple above the report should show the rows in DETAIL BAND and GROUPS LETTERS in COLUMN FOOTER with COUNT, like this:

```
  IN DETAIL: 
     ROW1
     ROW2
     ROW3
     ROW4
     ROW5

   IN FOOTER BAND:
     A - 2
     F - 2
     K - 1
```

How can i do it ?

Answer (score 2):

In the `footer` band you can include a subreport this is how the grouping could be done in the subreport.

**jrxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="subreport" pageWidth="555" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="0" rightMargin="0" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="c1d9b4b7-6162-4b17-b871-3cf3b867d1ef">
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="row" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="letter" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <variable name="letter_cnt" class="java.lang.Integer" resetType="Group" resetGroup="testGroup" calculation="Count">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{letter}]]></variableExpression>
        <initialValueExpression><![CDATA[0]]></initialValueExpression>
    </variable>
    <group name="testGroup">
        <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{letter}]]></groupExpression>
        <groupHeader>
            <band height="20">
                <textField>
                    <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20" uuid="f626bfda-d44c-491e-915b-d4b078e6f5cf"/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{letter}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField evaluationTime="Group" evaluationGroup="testGroup">
                    <reportElement x="100" y="0" width="100" height="20" uuid="6181956b-527f-4dca-8144-1846b4b8ef99"/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{letter_cnt}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
            </band>
        </groupHeader>
    </group>
</jasperReport>
```

As **output** gives

[image: result]

**However**, you can not use the main report datasource directly since this has already been iterated in the main report `detail` band, hence it is at last record.

If you are using a **connection** to provide data, I would suggest to query directly to have desired result (`sum` and `group by`).

If you are using a [JRDataSource](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JRDataSource.html) as the [JRBeanCollectionDataSource](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/data/JRBeanCollectionDataSource.html) you can re-initialized the datasource by using:

```
new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}.getData())
```

hence this is the datasource to pass to subreport

Comment: I'm using connection but i want to use the $P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}, this is possible ?

Comment: @Scientist You need to call moveFirst() on the data source this surely can be done from a java class inside of jrxml hmm (it returns void) I would need to do some testing on that.